# private yum/rpm repository in AWS S3 with basic authentication

Tags: amazon-s3, yum, basic-authentication

I need to create a yum repository. I want to store the files in S3 because: A) we already have a ton of files there; and B) because price is not bad (according to some definition of "not bad").

The repository needs to be private - yum clients will need to provide some kind of credentials to access it.

yum allows you to use Basic HTTP Authentication for private repos:

```
baseurl=https://user:pass@s3-site.whatever.com
```

I could enable Static Website Hosting on an S3 bucket, but it doesn't seem to support Basic Auth.

There's a yum plugin called [yum-s3-iam](https://github.com/seporaitis/yum-s3-iam) that allows you to setup access control based on the IAM role of the instance where yum is running, but this only works with instances in Amazon.

I could create a front-end instance, mount the S3 bucket to it with [s3fs](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse), install Apache with Basic Auth, but this would require running that front-end, which I'm trying to avoid (I want to reduce the number of moving parts).

Then there's the [s3auth](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/04/21/s3-http-basic-auth.html) proxy which basically does the same thing, but at a higher level. It still requires a front-end instance.

Is there a better solution, something that avoids the need to create a front-end instance?

Comment: That `yum-s3-iam` plugin appears to let you specify a `secret_key` in the repository config as well as supporting getting it from the an instance automatically. Does that do what you want?